# SEMrush flagging some external links as broken (error code 403, 500 etc) even though link is working fine?

Tags: seo, links, broken-links

SEMrush is flagging some of our pages as having broken external link even though the link is opening fine. This particular example is being flagged with http code 403 but we can open the link given on the page. Please suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: Unfortunately individual website troubleshooting, including via third-party products, is considered off-topic here. You can simply test the URL on other testing sites to see what they're returning.

Comment: Though its my first time here, but I think SEO related tools are quite important part of this whole exercise. And what other way is there to clearly communicate the issue than giving one concrete example. It feels like someone flagging your question on stackoverflow because you have code snippet (which would be always very specific). But what I find most useful on stackoverflow is that by looking some very specific related problem of other I can find out solution for my own

Comment: It's always best to have a look at the Stack Exchange site's [What topics can I ask about here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) prior to posting. If you click on that link, you'll see that questions [specific to only your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here, as are those that are out of your control, which SEMrush is. We really can't know why a third-party site did what it did...

Answer (score 1):

The website https://httpstatus.io/ is returning a '200' status for that page, so I suppose it is SEMrush that is mistaken.

Have you tried recrawling the page? Perhaps it was a one-off issue.

Alternatively, what did the SEMrush support team have to say about this?

Comment: The page is ok, it is the external link which is being flagged with http code 403. But if I click on the link, it opens correctly

Comment: A link doesn't have a status code. Pages have status codes, links don't.

Comment: Ofcourse ! it's just the names I am using to distinguish between my page and the external page whose link is given on my page.

Comment: Is there a way to mark this as fixed within SEMRush? For example, within Google Search Console, this often flags errors which are no longer an issue. I mark these as fixed and wait for them to re-crawl.